# Would like to see example "HTML Snippet" from Google Adsense API

Tags: html, api, adsense

Google Adsnse has an API that you can use (if you qualify) to generate Adsense ads on your site.  The core feature is the function generateAdCode that returns "an HTML snippet that can be dropped into an HTML page for the page to start receiving Google Ads."

Try as hard as I could, I couldn't find a basic example of what that returned "HTML snippet" will look like.

Can anyone please enlighten me?

(Of course, I can make some strong assumptions, but I rather see something more definite.)

FYI, I am simply trying to understand the intricacies of using Google Adsense from all the different angles.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What they mean by HTML snippet is actually a JavaScript snippet which in turn generates HTML. Just visit any page with Google Ads on it and check out the (rendered) source code to see what Google Adsense publishes on your site.